# Can I bind a jquery plugin at button click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to attach a plugin at runtime.The following code doesn't work.Maybe I think wrong way.Let me know the way you think.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.show').click(function(){
     $('div.gallery img').slideGallery();
   });
});
<button class='show'>SHOW</button>
<div class="gallery">
//Images will appear from database by server side language.
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do like this? You can attach the gallery in document ready event itself.

Comment: @rahul yeah! You are right. But I can't define the images that will come out from DB. that why

Comment: `$('div.gallery img')` will fetch all the images inside the div with class name 'gallery`.

Comment: @rahul http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGalleryDemo1.htm that plugin can't working in document.ready so I try to bind in the button click.

Answer (score 0):

The link that you posted is working fine for me.

Include the script file jquery.slidingGallery-1.2.min.js.

Call the plugin method in document ready event. It should work fine.

```
$(function(){
    $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery();
});
```

For this code to work you need to have images inside the div with class name `gallery`.

If you want to handle runtime generated elements then you might need to look into [**livequery**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery).

Comment: ) you are miss understanding. I mean I making call plugin at document.ready but at that time no images in div.gallery when I choose some group of gallery that image will render dynamically.That plugin can't working at that time so I try to rebind button click event.